# Mac OS X: finder window keeps opening by itself and stealing focus

Tags: mac, finder, focus

I have a Macbook with Mac OS X 10.4.11 here, with an annoying problem. After starting the computer and logging in, the finder keeps stealing focus. You can go back to your working app, but a minute later, it steals focus again. Even as I'm typing this message, I had to reslect firefox two times.

At some point it stops, but how often it pops up/steals focus first is kind of random, it seems.

The finder menu at the top of the screen also flickers sometimes when it does that, so it seems it's not just the window that opens, but that finder completely restarts. (the behavior is the same when I press shift-command click, and then restart the finder).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I already looked under startup items in accounts/login, but that all seems normal. I also removed com.apple.finder.plist, as was suggested somewhere.

edit: Upon examination, it seemed that finder kept crashing. Here is a crashlog:

Host Name:      monster
Date/Time:      2010-07-15 10:42:01.318 +0200
OS Version:     10.4.11 (Build 8S2167)
Report Version: 4

Command: Finder
Path:    /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
Parent:  WindowServer [61]

Version:        10.4.7 (10.4.7)
Build Version:  3
Project Name:   Finder_FE
Source Version: 5292900

PID:    231
Thread: 3

Exception:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (0x0002)
Code[0]:    0x0000000d
Code[1]:    0x00000000

Thread 0:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9fe48cd7 mach_msg_trap + 7
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x9082d227 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 2014
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x9082ca42 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 61
3   com.apple.HIToolbox                 0x92df1878 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 285
4   com.apple.HIToolbox                 0x92df0f82 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 385
5   com.apple.HIToolbox                 0x92e39a74 _AcquireNextEvent + 58
6   com.apple.HIToolbox                 0x92e398bc RunApplicationEventLoop + 150
7   com.apple.finder                    0x00007deb 0x1000 + 28139
8   com.apple.finder                    0x00004c6b 0x1000 + 15467
9   com.apple.finder                    0x000515b6 0x1000 + 329142
10  com.apple.finder                    0x000514dd 0x1000 + 328925

Thread 1:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9fe65d5c kevent + 12
1   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore      0x90cb8d0c PrivateMPEntryPoint + 51
2   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9fe63227 _pthread_body + 84

Thread 2:
0   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9fe638c7 semaphore_wait_signal_trap + 7
1   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore      0x90cb8eb2 MPWaitOnQueue + 198
2   com.apple.DesktopServices           0x9271f943 TNodeSyncTask::SyncTaskProc(void*) + 143
3   ...ple.CoreServices.CarbonCore      0x90cb8d0c PrivateMPEntryPoint + 51
4   libSystem.B.dylib                   0x9fe63227 _pthread_body + 84

Thread 3 Crashed:
0   <<00000000>>        0x90024689 0 + -1878899063

Thread 3 crashed with X86 Thread State (32-bit):
  eax: 0x017ca000  ebx: 0x017ce977  ecx: 0x00000000  edx: 0x017ce9c1
  edi: 0xffffffff  esi: 0xffffffff  ebp: 0x017cbff8  esp: 0x017cbf9c
   ss: 0x0000001f  efl: 0x00010296  eip: 0x90024689   cs: 0x00000017
   ds: 0x0000001f   es: 0x0000001f   fs: 0x00000000   gs: 0x00000000

Binary Images Description:
    0x1000 -   0x2ccfff com.apple.finder 10.4.7 /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
  0x5b5000 -   0x5b6fff com.apple.textencoding.unicode 2.1      /System/Library/TextEncodings/Unicode Encodings.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Unicode Encodings
0x14f01000 - 0x14f6efff com.DivXInc.DivXDecoder 6.6.0   /Library/QuickTime/DivX Decoder.component/Contents/MacOS/DivX Decoder
0x8fe00000 - 0x8fe4afff dyld 46.16      /usr/lib/dyld
0x90000000 - 0x90016fff com.apple.CoreVideo 1.4.2       /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/Versions/A/CoreVideo
0x9002a000 - 0x90348fff com.apple.QuickTime 7.6.0 (1290)        /System/Library/Frameworks/Qu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After googling some more, I found a lot of different reasons for this crash and one of which fixed it for me.

I updated quicktime and the problem seems to be gone.

Answer (score 3):

If it is *Finder* that is crashing, you should see fresh crash logs in `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/Finder.crash.log`. You can use the *Console* application (`/Applications/Utilities/Console.app`) to view the file.

The stack traces from such crashes might give you a clue as to why it is crashing.

If the crashes consistently indicate some third-party code (e.g. a “haxie” or similar “injected” code), then you might try quiting/uninstalling whatever application is injecting the code.

If you are also seeing crashes of various other applications, it might be a hardware problem (i.e. bad memory). You could also check `/var/log/system.log` (system.log in *Console*) for things like disk I/O errors, etc.

Comment: Finder indeed crashed. I edited my post with the crashlog.

Answer (score 2):

- Peek into the log files: see Applications, Utilities, Console.
- Though removing your current account's Finder's `plist` didn't help, maybe create a new account to see if things are the same for a fresh user? System Preferences, System, Accounts.
- Check the digital signature of Finder. Copy the first line into Applications, Utilities, Terminal:

  > codesign --verify -vv /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app

  ...which (on 10.6.3, maybe this is not present on 10.4 yet?) should give you:

  > /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app: valid on disk
  >   /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
- Enable [the "Quit Finder" menu option](http://lifehacker.com/333819/add-quit-to-the-finder-menu) and quit Finder. Finder should then only (automatically) come back if you stop all other applications as well. Does it still come back while you're using your browser? (Quitting Finder will also temporarily hide your Desktop. No worries!)

Comment: The OP says this is on 10.4 (there was no *codesign* in that release).

Comment: Digital signatures were already used in OS 9, but indeed `codesign` was [not introduced until 10.5](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2007/tn2206.html). Does anyone know of any other way to see if Finder was signed in OS 10.4?

Comment: I created another user, which does not suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Google Drive installed, try unchecking "Show file sync status icons and right click menu" in the Google Drive preferences. This is a known bug.

[image: Screenshot of Setting]